# Grafana: How to have the duration for a selected period

Tags: graphite, grafana

I can't find the correct mathematical formula to compute a SLA (availability) with Grafana:
I have graph to show the duration of downtime for each days:
[image: Graph here]
From this, i would like to compute the SLA (eg: 99,5%).

On the graph for the selected period (Last 7 days) i can to have this data:

- 71258 is the sum of duration of downtime in second. I have this with summarize(1day, max, false)
- I need to have the sum of duration of time for the selected period (here 7 days = 604800second). But how ?

If i have this last data, after i will do :

> (100% * 604800) / 71258 = X %
>
> 100% - X % = My SLA!!

My question is: Which formula use to have the duration for a selected period in Grafana ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36364407/356729

Answer (score -1):

One of the database you can run behind Grafana, is [Axibase Time Series Database](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/) (ATSD). It provides built-in aggregation functions that can perform SLA-type calculations, for example, to compute % of the period when the value exceeded the threshold.

- THRESHOLD_COUNT - number of violations in the period
- THRESHOLD_DURATION - cumulative duration of the violations
- THRESHOLD_PERCENT - duration divided by period

In your example, that would be THRESHOLD_PERCENT.

Here's a sample SLA report for Amazon Web Services instance: https://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/0aa34311/6/. THRESHOLD_PERCENT is visualized on the top chart.

[image: AWS SLA report]

The API request looks as follows:

```
{
    "queries": [{
        "startDate": "2016-02-22T00:00:00Z",
        "endDate": "2016-02-23T00:00:00Z",
        "timeFormat": "iso",
        "entity": "nurswgvml007",
        "metric": "app.response_time",
        "aggregate": {
            "types": [
                "THRESHOLD_COUNT",
                "THRESHOLD_DURATION",
                "THRESHOLD_PERCENT"
            ],
            "period": {
                "count": 1,
                "unit": "HOUR"
            },
            "threshold": {
                "max": 200
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

ATSD driver: https://github.com/grafana/grafana-plugins/tree/master/datasources/atsd

Disclosure: I work for Axibase.