# Time series database that computes integral

Tags: time-series

I have a data sets that contains the following information:

```
Device # | Timestamp  | In Error (1=yes, 0=false)
       1 | 1459972740 | 1
       1 | 1459972745 | 1
       1 | 1459972750 | 0
       1 | 1459972755 | 1
       2 | 1459972740 | 0
       2 | 1459972745 | 1
       2 | 1459972750 | 1
       2 | 1459972755 | 1
...
```

I would like to compute the number of minutes a device has been in error in a specific period. ie: "How much downtime (in minutes) did we had per device yesterday". Which would lead to "What is our device with the most downtime yesterday", "What is our average error time per device per day", etc

I would assume that this is a classic use case for time series but I can't find any product that can compute integral aggregation on this dataset. Note that the engine must be able to assume a value based on the previous snapshot. In my example, if I request the downtime per device between 1459972742 and 1459972752, the output should be 8ms for device #1 and 7ms for device #2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Axibase Time Series Database](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/) provides both the API and visualization for threshold aggregation functions that can compute SLA/outage metrics.

[Grafana: How to have the duration for a selected period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398159/grafana-how-to-have-the-duration-for-a-selected-period/36408434#36408434)

In your case threshold would be 1:

```
"threshold": {
     "max": 1
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

[VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) provides `integrate()` function, which can be used for calculating the integral over the given duration. For example, the following [MetricsQL query](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) calculates the integral for the given `metric` over the last 24 hours:

```
integrate(metric[24h])
```